# Python: Why flawfinder module is not working in cmd windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flawfinder

Python `flawfinder` module is working in bash but not working in Windows command commandline. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Python installation path - C/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python

   `pip install flawfinder`
2. When I type `flawfinder` in commandline, it gives below error:

   > flawfinder is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   >   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows the recommended way is to install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) and install flawfinder on top of it. This is the usual way. From [Docs](https://dwheeler.com/flawfinder/),

> Flawfinder works on Unix-like systems (it’s been tested on GNU/Linux),
>   and on Windows by using Cygwin.

But it can also be made to work with python by running it as a script.

- Download the flawfinder.py script [from here](https://dwheeler.com/flawfinder/flawfinder)
- Run it with python as usual in your cmd prompt like,

  `python flawfinder [options] [source_code_file]+`

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.0.16 released 2021-05-31 `flawfinder` also works on windows as expected.